# Como crear un juego multijugador online

Tags: android, android-studio, base-de-datos

Buenas comunidad, hice un pequeño juego para android al cual me gustaria agregarle un modo de juego online contra otra persona, me gustaria que me orienten como se haria esto, si tengo que crear una base de datos etc, no necesito que me expliquen paso a paso sino que me orienten donde investigar, muchas gracias

Comment: Una alternativa es utilizando Google Play Juegos. Este artículo (*en inglés*) puede interesarte: [Adding Real-time Multiplayer Support to Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer)

Comment: Esta pregunta es un poco amplia y no sé si se ajusta bien al formato de SOes. Las respuestas que vas a recibir van a ser o muy genéricas, o demasiado extensas. Y eso si no son sólo enlaces a diferentes tutoriales online (algo que te vendría bien, pero que no creo que entre dentro del alcance del sitio).

Comment: Personalmente creo que podría aceptarse, sólo porque el autor plantea "*no necesito que me expliquen paso a paso sino que me orienten donde investigar*" y no es un tema que salga directamente de una búsqueda en Google. Pero no estoy seguro (no voto ni a favor ni en contra).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo leas

[Adding Real-time Multiplayer Support to Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer) (inglés)

En github se encuentran ejemplos para implementar juegos multijugador.

https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples

La mayoria de la documentación no se encuentra en español pero recomiendo abras los ejemplos en tu IDE para que revises la implementación.